# How can I get a total from specific data that I've filtered in the UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, oracle

I've retrieved a list from the DB that contains colors. Then, I filtered them in the UI to count how many I have from each color.

```
        OutModelListCnt.RED_CNT = OutModelList.Filter(p => p.COLORS.Equals("RED")).Count.ToString(); 
        OutModelListCnt.GREEN_CNT = OutModelList.Filter(p => p.COLORS.Equals("GREEN")).Count.ToString();  
        OutModelListCnt.BLUE_CNT = OutModelList.Filter(p => p.COLORS.Equals("BLUE")).Count.ToString();  
        OutModelListCnt.WHITE_CNT = OutModelList.Filter(p => p.COLORS.Equals("WHITE")).Count.ToString();
        OutModelListCnt.PINK_CNT = OutModelList.Filter(p => p.COLORS.Equals("PINK")).Count.ToString();
        OutModelListCnt.BLACK_CNT = OutModelList.Filter(p => p.COLORS.Equals("BLACK")).Count.ToString();
```

This is working perfectly fine. It retrieves how many I have from each:

```
RED    = 3
GREEN  = 2
BLUE   = 7
WHITE  = 4
PINK   = 0
BLACK  = 8
```

My question is how can I get the total count of the RED+GREEN+BLUE together, since I'm filtering the list in the UI and not from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Linq query, using Where Operator with multiple OR ( || ) conditions

```
var count = OutModelList.Where(c => c.COLORS.Equals("RED") || c => c.COLORS.Equals("GREEN") || c => c.COLORS.Equals("BLUE")).Count()
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be more useful to the OP if you added a brief explanation as to why this works.

Comment: I updated the answer, let me know if you have any questions.